# Reset branch with commits to its initial state

Tags: git

Say I'm on branch xyz which was created on the basis of development branch. I'd like to get rid of all my changes (including those commited and pushed) and have the state of xyz branch the same as the development branch, e.g. I don't want any modifications I've made to xyz.

I tried `git reset --hard origin/development` and after that `git clean -f -d` but it didn't do the trick.

**EDIT**

`git status` says:

> On branch SVP-xyz
>   Your branch and 'origin/xyz' have diverged,
>   and have 8 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
>     (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: It sounds like that should work fine - what actually happened?

Comment: Ehmm. Just delete local and remote `xyz` branch?

Comment: Despite of those command, I still have files I created, which weren't on the development branch.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Yes, I thought about it and it would be my last resort. I wonder whether this could be avoided.

Comment: have you tried `git rebase --abort`? (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: No, I have not. Should I try it? What is it suppose to do?

Comment: @menteith: What do `git status` and `git log` show? If you just delete the new local files, does that get back to where you want?

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes, if I manually delete the files I've made I have the state of development branch, which is what I wanted. I had to remove few files, however, I looked for better solution in case if there would be more files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `xyz` branch is already on remote, I can't see the way to reset the changes there without rewriting the history (which, of course, is not recommended).

So, I'd go with deleting local and remote `xyz` branches, and just recreate them from your `dev` branch:

1. Checkout to `dev` or any other branch (basically step away from `xyz`):

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
2. Remove both local and remote `xyz` branches:

   ```
   git push -d origin xyz
   git branch -d xyz
   ```
3. Create a new branch `xyz` branch from your `dev` branch:

   ```
   git checkout -b xyz dev
   ```
4. Push your new `xyz` branch to remote (if you need to):

   ```
   git push -u origin xyz
   ```

Comment: P.S.: Of course, as always with git, there should be multiple ways of doing this. Perhaps even with one or two commands. But since I prefer dumb proven approach with commands I remember out of the head - I made this as simple as possible.

Comment: What's the difference between deleting the remote `xyz` branch and then recreating it, vs just force-pushing the rewritten one?

Comment: Good point. Rewriting the history is a bad practice, and might screw up other people work. But in reality the outcome between what I've posted and rewriting history could result to the same issues. Unless you give a new name to your new branch.

Comment: I think it's worth being practical here: I don't generally rewrite history for "main" (project-named) forks, but on my own fork (even a publicly available one) I regard it as fair game.